# get parent id from mysql query based on condition

Tags: mysql, sql, join, having-clause

i got two tables one is parent_table and one child_table.

what i need to get is the id from parent_table when the status equal to 0 when child_table status is not equal to 0 and only if its not equal to 0

for example tables goes like that:

parent_table

```
id , status
--------------------
1 , 0
2 , 0
```

child_table

```
id , parent_id, status
------------------------

1  ,   2      , 2
2  ,   2      , 1
3  ,   2      , 1
```

what i need to get is the id of parent table and only if the status of child table status are not 0

this is what i tried:

```
SELECT a.id FROM `parent_table` a inner join child_table b where b.status !=0 and a.status = 0 and a.id = b.parent_id
```

the result i need is : id 2 from parent_table

thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join both tables, aggregate by parent id, and use a `having` clause to filter out parents whose any child has status `0`:

```
select p.id
from parent_table p
inner join child_table c on c.parent_id = p.id
group by p.id
having max(c.status = 0) = 0
```

Actually, you can get the same result directly from the child table:

```
select parent_id
from child_table
group by parent_id
having max(status = 0) = 0
```

Comment: Thanks GMB the first did it right but only missing is that parent status need to equal to 0 , here is the working query : select p.id from parent_table p inner join child_table c on c.id = p.id where p.status= 0 group by p.id having max(c.status= 0) = 0 ,thanks :)